# Return "_id" for individual tr in User table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mongodb, flask

I have a user table which is looped using python - flask & HTML.

```
    <tr>
     {% for user in userTable %}
     <td>{{ user["school"] }}</td>
     <td>{{ user["name"] }}</td>
     <td>{{ user["surname"] }}</td>
     <td>{{ user["user_id"] }}</td>
     {% endfor %}
</tr>
```

How would i click an individual row and that would return the Object Id -"_id" or even user_id from the mongodb.

[My user table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyLVN.jpg)

Comment: So what did you try? Set an id on the tr, add onclick handler, read the attribute.

Comment: Possibly put the `_id` value "in the table" then! And possibly as a "hidden field" if you don't want to display it. If you are asking "how do I look that up?", then surely since it's already in the results you use to render, then a separate request to "retrieve" would just be inefficient. You retrived the data already. So use it!

Comment: I have used jQuery, which pops up an alert to let me know what row i have picked. But that isnt what i want, i want to return the _id from the mongodb

Comment: Dude `user['_id']`. It's already there.

Comment: I might need to clarify. Say if i click Sinead Smiths row in user table (see picture) how would i disinguish onclick what row was choosen, and from that get the user_id

Answer (score 0):

First, you have logical error, then i add some things (assuming you have user_id column in table, if not, rename to existing Id column):

```
{% for user in userTable %}
 <tr user-id="{{ user["user_id"] }}">
  <td>{{ user["school"] }}</td>
  <td>{{ user["name"] }}</td>
  <td>{{ user["surname"] }}</td>
  <td>{{ user["user_id"] }}</td>
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

jQuery:

```
   $("tr").click(function(){
      var userId = $(this).attr("user-id");
      alert (userId);
   })
```